# What is the real size of the non-pruned Bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: blockexplorer

My node (via Bitcoin Explorer) tells me as of now: 340.98 GB
[image]
Most website online: 280-300 GB

**Why is there such a large delta?**

Comment: In what way does your node tell you this?

Comment: @PieterWuille I use a RaspiBlitz and can get Blockchain stats with help of the web app "Bitcoin Explorer". See newly added sccreenshot. (Wow - what an honour to get reply from a Bitcoin VIP...)

Comment: It says data size. Your node stores a lot more data than just the blockchain (also undo data, utxo set database, indexes, and a few smaller things like mempool, wallet(s), ...).

Comment: Understood. Thanks so much!